# Garbage space in files using \r\n

Tags: c++, qt, file, text

Let's say I save some words in a `.txt` file.  I want to be every word in newline. I save the words like this

```
tempE << line << "\r\n" ;
```

Every time this code executes, I think after every word, it will add invisible space that I can't see in text file, but when I read the whole line of every word in LineEdit I see plus space that will ruin my other part of program. I try to use

```
tempE << line << std::endl ;   
tempE << line << "\n" ;
```

but none of them even create newline.  By the way, I put my code here since it may be that the issue is from somewhere else.
My code will delete the first word of first line of text and replace it with another word.

```
void MainWindow::on_modify_clicked()
{
    makeFa();
    ofstream tempE;
    const int x=0;
    int y=0;
    QMessageBox msg;
    int ret;
    msg.setText("Are you sure you want to Modify this words?");
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    ret= msg.exec();
    switch(ret){
    case QMessageBox::Yes:
               QString input;
               string line;
               string EnWord;
               ifstream DataE;
               //open En
               DataE.open("En1.txt");
               tempE.open("tempE.txt");
               DataE>>EnWord;
               DataE.close();
               DataE.open("En1.txt");
               while(getline(DataE,line)){
                          if(line!= EnWord){
                              tempE<<line<<"\r\n";
                          }
                          else{
                              QString input=ui->InEN->text();
                              tempE<<input.toStdString()<<"\r\n";
                          }
               }
               DataE.close();
               tempE.close();

               remove("En1.txt");
               rename("tempE.txt","En1.txt");
               break;
    }
}
```

Comment: new line is just "\n", and that works as expected, so I'm not able to reproduce your problem.  In Qt you can use [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) and related methdos. I think you problem is in your function logic, not standard functions.

Comment: Are you running the program on Linux (Unix) or Windows?  Presumably, on Windows since `\r\n` line endings are primarily an issue there (unless you're dealing with Internet protocols; they often use CRLF line endings).  In theory, if you create a text file stream, writing `\n` should give you the native line ending (which would be CRLF on Windows), and reading a native line ending should translate to just `\n` on input.  So, in theory, using `"\n"` or `endl` to end lines on output should yield native CRLF line endings, and reading words should skip the line endings pretty much regardless.